# Can I change Synapse shortcut to Super/Windows key alone?

Tags: shortcut-keys, synapse

When I try to edit the synapse config it does not allow me to use the left <kbd>Super</kbd> as a shortcut to invoke it. Is there a round-about way that I can go through.

[image: Synapse Configuration]

When I just press the Windows/Super key the configuration window does not acknowledge it. However, a combination shortcut (such as <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>) does work fine.

Since I'm using Precise, with Unity, I'd also need a way to change the default dash behaviour for Windows/Super key to something else.

Comment: I'd also like to do that, I'm using Xubuntu, so there is no keyboard conflict with anything, still Synapse doesn't allow me to do that...

Comment: @Borsook Try editing the `~/.config/hotkeys/synapse/synapse.hotkeys` file. It doesn't work in Ubuntu due to Unity for me, might work for you.

Comment: @Borsook You can set an XFCE shortcut in the "Application Shortcuts" tab in the Keyboard settings app. Just set it to execute "/usr/bin/synapse".

Comment: I don't think you can create a shortcut of just 'super'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> See better answer below this one.

You must bind the action to the <kbd>Super</kbd>'s scancode or keycode; normal hotkeys record the state of the modifier keys and throw away their keypress events; so you never see something that reacts to just pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>, but instead to the <kbd>A</kbd> key plus the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key's recorded state.

The hotkey library in use is libgtkhotkey (0.2 on 12.04) and it doesn't support using the key press event from modifier's. You'd have to write your own patch to catch that and perhaps support such a thing in the signature format.

All tests with the existing signature format failed to produce anything but an error.

Comment: This answer is wrong.  The correct answer is the one below by jnas.

Answer (score 13):

I know this is a little old now but thought solution by be useful anyway.

First remove any super key bindings e.g. `<super>+p` is a common one for screen settings

Then close Synapse

In        `~/.config/hotkeys/synapse.hotkeys`

change

```
Signature=<Control>space
```

to

```
Signature=Super_L
```

Relaunch Synapse

Comment: New install of synapse on 12.10 from PPA (ver 0.2.10-2ubuntu1); there's nothing in `config.json` related to "activate", however the first step seems to do the trick.

Comment: **This answer is outdated**

Answer (score 12):

In later versions of synapse installed from the launchpad ppa the setting is in `.config/synapse/config.json`. Edit it while synapse is closed to specify `Super_L` as activation key.

```
{
  "ui" : {
    "shortcuts" : {
      "activate" : "Super_L",
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

Note: In some environments the key should be specified as `"Super"`.

See [https://launchpad.net/~synapse-core/+archive/ubuntu/testing](https://launchpad.net/%7Esynapse-core/+archive/ubuntu/testing).

Comment: this should work although Super_L is not proper "shortcut encoding" is should be more in line of <Alt>space

Comment: This worked on synapse 0.2.99 running on lubuntu 18.04

Comment: **This is the good answer!**

Answer (score 4):

A temporary workaround is to remove the modifier from super and remap the key to a "normal key" you do not use. I choose "µ", which is named "mu".

`xmodmap -e 'keysym Super_L = mu mu mu'`

`xmodmap -e 'clear Mod4'`

The first command will pretty much make super useless for anything else than typing "µ" and the second command will clear all Mod4 modifiers (I do not use them anyway). Use xev to find the name of a key, look for a line similar to:

```
state 0x80, keycode 58 (keysym 0xb5, mu), same_screen YES,
```

The changes will be lost after logging out. To make them permanent, add the commands to your `.bashrc` OR create a file named `.Xmodmap` in your home directory with the content:

```
keysym Super_L = mu mu mu

clear Mod4
```

If you mess up while playing around with xmodmap, just log out and log back in again to restore your old settings.

I've only tested with this one key, and I can still type µ by pressing <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> without having Synapse pop up. I also tried remapping <kbd>Super</kbd> to <kbd>Page Up</kbd>;  Synapse was able to detect the key while entering it in the settings, but failed to open the launcher when pressing it.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently `~/.config/synapse/` doesn't exist anymore.

I just installed synapse on XUBUNTU 12.04.02 and changing the Signature entry in

`~/.config/hotkeys/synapse/synapse.hotkeys`

was enough to have synapse pop up with a single hit on the Super-key.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign it the super key shortcut via Settings Manager->Keyboard->Application Shortcuts tab

add synapse
then set its shortcut as super key.

Wish you good luck!