# Re-map 'Super' key to launch an app

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys, synapse

how could I re-map the 'Super' (left) key to launch an app? I want to launch Synapse with it, which is far more responsive than the Unity launcher. Cheers.

Comment: You might want to look into `xbindkeys` (http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/xbindkeys.1.html) and `xmodmap` (http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/xmodmap.1.html).

Comment: @MichaelBiech xbindkeys doesn't work for the super key, moreover, xbindkeys only adds behavior, I assume the OP also wants to unbind the Unity Launcher...

Comment: @GerhardBurger: Using xbindkeys with "Super_L" works perfectly fine for me. I pointed out xmodmap for precisely that reason, though: It _might_ not work out of the box, so something along the lines of `xmodmap -e "remove mod4 = Super_L"` might be in order to stop it from being recognized as a modifier. Your point about the OP wanting to unbind the Unity launcher from Super_L is very valid, though and I didn't take it into account. Also you're right about adding complexity typically not being a good thing.

Comment: @MichaelBiech, that is strange, I tried adding it to `.xbindkeyrc` and that didn't work... Could you tell me how you got it working? Also the `xmodmap -e "remove mod4 = Super_L"` didn't seem to do anything. I'm very interested in solutions to this question, if you have some time could you have a look at [my question about Ubuntu key bindings in general](http://askubuntu.com/questions/243751/how-are-key-codes-mapped-to-the-appropriate-action) (unanswered)?

Comment: `Super_L` didn't work for me either.

Comment: Actually, `Super_L` worked after I rebooted.   I've never had to reboot to get `xbindkeys` working before..

Comment: @GerhardBurger To be fair, I'm using `i3` for my window manager, so what I said can not simply be applied to a more "default" Ubuntu desktop. Sorry I couldn't be of more help on this one.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I change Synapse shortcut to Super/Windows key alone?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/174838/can-i-change-synapse-shortcut-to-super-windows-key-alone)

Answer (score 0):

The 'Super' button can be set as an activation key in the configuration file for Synapse.

See [Can I change Synapse shortcut to Super/Windows key alone?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/174838/can-i-change-synapse-shortcut-to-super-windows-key-alone)