# Binding Synapse shortcut to key-release instead of key-press

Tags: 14.04, shortcut-keys, gnome-classic, synapse

#### Background

So I've already referred a question that demonstrates how to bind the Synapse launcher to the "Super (Win) Key". ([Can I change Synapse shortcut to Super/Windows key alone?](https://askubuntu.com/q/174838/246606))

The problem is that combinations involving the Super key now all launch Synapse.

I believe this is happening because Synapse is being activated on the button-press event rather than on the button-release event as would happen with, say, Unity or while using it on Windows.

#### Question

Is there any way in Ubuntu to bind a shortcut to the button-release event? That way I can use the Super button in other combinations, like "Super + D" for show desktop or something.

#### Environment

I'm using the Gnome (Compiz) Flashback session environment on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Comment: What desktop environment are you using?

Comment: I just updated information about the environment. Basically it's Gnome shell flashback session.

Answer (score 4):

`ksuperkey` worked well for me. I followed the instructions here:

https://blog.hanschen.org/2012/10/17/open-application-launcher-with-super-key/

Except, I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 + MATE, so what I did was:

a) Removed Alt+F1 as the shortcut for the MATE menu in Preferences --> Hardware --> Keyboard Shortcuts

[image]

b) Set Alt+F1 as the Synapse shortcut:

```
cat ~/.config/synapse/config.json       {
          "ui" : {
            "global" : {
              "ui-type" : "default"
            },
            "shortcuts" : {
              "activate" : "<Alt>F1"
            }
          }
        }
```

c) Installed and ran `ksuperkey`

`ksuperkey` now does the mapping from the release of the Win key (Super key) to `Alt+F1`, which triggers MATE to launch Synapse. At the same time, other combinations involving Win work fine without invoking Synapse. (In particular, I set up Win + M to minimize all windows and show the Desktop and that's important to me).

Note that `ksuperkey` is quite flexible and the can map the release of any key to send any key combination, not just Alt+F1 (the default).

d) Added ksuperkey to Startup Applications