# How to activate/deactivate synapse with super key shortcut in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: shortcuts, synapse

I want to activate/deactivate synapse with <kbd>Super</kbd> key shortcut in Ubuntu 16.04, I tried old solutions in this site but I still can't change the shortcut.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I change Synapse shortcut to Super/Windows key alone?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/174838/can-i-change-synapse-shortcut-to-super-windows-key-alone)

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/511236/925128

Answer (score 0):

There is no "simple" solution. To assign an action to just pressing the <kbd>Super</kbd> key requires a specific tool, `ksuperkey`.

The utility `ksuperkey` lets you assign any action to pressing and releasing the <kbd>Super</kbd> key alone (and other keys if you wish). It will not interfere with uses of the <kbd>Super</kbd> key as a modifier for other keys.

The tool `ksuperkey` [is on Github](https://github.com/hanschen/ksuperkey). It is not available in the Ubuntu repositories. Probably, as I did, you will need to compile the utility yourself according to the instructions on the Github page. Do not be afraid: it is an easy compile.

*Edit 2019-06-05*: A software repository for ksuperkey is available for easier installation: https://launchpad.net/~mehanik/+archive/ubuntu/ksuperkey */Edit*

Once loaded, the tool intercepts pressing and releasing <kbd>Super</kbd> and remaps that by default to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, in many desktops a hotkey for the menuing system. Using command line options, that mapping can be changed.

Thus, create a script that does what you want, in this case toggling synapse. Assign it the hotkey <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>. ksuperkey, which you preferably have autostarted when you log in, will call this hotkey when you press and release kbd>Super.

If you want to preserve the current binding of <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, then assign another shortcut of your choice to your script. In that case, you will need to autostart `ksuperkey` with appropriate command line options to remap to the hotkey you have chosen. Help on the command line options is available on the [Github page](https://github.com/hanschen/ksuperkey).