# GNOME - Rebind Super key to custom keybinding

Tags: gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys, wayland

I've removed the default GNOME keybinding to the Super key and I tried to rebind it using gsettings to its own key:

```
matt@hydrogen:~$ gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys custom-keybindings
['/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom0/']
matt@hydrogen:~$ gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom0/ binding
'<Super>'
```

Setting it with gsettings works fine, but it doesn't work.

In the GNOME Settings GUI it shows up as "Disabled":

[image: GNOME Settings Custom Keybindings, where the custom keybinding is shown as disabled]

But when clicking on it, it shows that it is bound to the Super key:
[image: GNOME Settings that shows that the keybinding is set to the Super key]

I've considered using xbindkeys, but this unfortunately doesn't support Wayland, which I am currently using. Obviously it seems like GNOME doesn't like me doing this, but are there any possible workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

Changing the behaviour of pressing and releasing <kbd>Super</kbd> will, as far as I know, require the use of a utility `ksuperkey`. See [my answer here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1109368/how-to-activate-deactivate-synapse-with-super-key-shortcut-in-ubuntu-16-04/1109375#1109375) for some more background on ksuperkey and where to find it. One caveat: Probably the utility will work fine in Wayland, but I am not sure.

The first thing you need to do in any case is disable the <kbd>Super</kbd> key for showing the overview:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.mutter overlay-key ''
```

You could now first try if your own approach now works. If it does, let us know because that would be most straightforward. I doubt it, however, and then you can try using ksuperkey.

Once started, ksuperkey by default redirects pressing and releasing <kbd>Super</kbd> to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>. There are two possible approaches: 1) you rebind <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to your custom command (by default in Gnome, it shows the "menu", i.e., the overview) or 2) you redirect to another keyboard combination by launching ksuperkey with the `-e` option, e.g.

```
ksuperkey -e 'Super_L=Control_L|space'
```

will redirect <kbd>Super</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>.

The utility must be running, so you will need to have it autostart after login.

Comment: Thanks for your response! It does seem to generate the keycodes correctly _except_ when I'm focused on a GNOME-y window. So for example, in Settings and Terminal it doesn't work at all.